# How to check radio button is checked on form submit - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, checked

I have a form using radio buttons for the user to select a rating between 1-10. Some of these questions are required to have a rating before the user is able to submit. So i call for the function validateForm() on submit to do so.

Example of radio buttons:

```
          <div class="fluid_container">
    <label for="ease-rating-0">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-0" value="0" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">0</div>
    </label>

      <label for="ease-rating-1">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-1" value="1" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">1</div>
</label>

      <label for="ease-rating-2">
 <input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-2" value="2" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">2</div>
</label>

      <label for="ease-rating-3">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-3" value="3" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">3</div>
</label>

      <label for="ease-rating-4">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-4" value="4" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">4</div>
</label>  
          
          
    <label for="ease-rating-5">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-5" value="5" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">5</div>
</label>

      <label for="ease-rating-6">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-6" value="6" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">6</div>
</label>

      <label for="ease-rating-7">
 <input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-7" value="7" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">7</div>
            </label>

      <label for="ease-rating-8">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-8" value="8" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">8</div>
            </label>

      <label for="ease-rating-9">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-9" value="9" />
<div class="box-number-half number-padding">9</div>
</label>
          
         
      <label for="ease-rating-10">
<input type="radio" name="ease-rating" class="hover-select-ease" id="ease-rating-10" value="10" />
<div class="box-number-half">10</div>
</label>
      </div>
```

An example of my form:
[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxnZz.png)

I have success with the following code for "ease of placing order" question:

```
function validateForm() {
    var easeradios = document.getElementsByName("ease-rating");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < easeradios.length; i++) {
        if (easeradios[i].checked) {
        return true;
        }
    } return false;
}
```

I am grabbing the radio buttons by their name which for this is ease-rating. This works fine and the user cannot submit until a rating is selected on this question. However when i try to apply the same to the next row as this is also required it seems to go wrong.

```
    function validateForm() {


var easeradios = document.getElementsByName("ease-rating");

for (var i = 0; i < easeradios.length; i++) {
    if (easeradios[i].checked) {
    return true;
    }
} return false;


var convradios = document.getElementsByName("conv-rating");

for (var i = 0; i < convradios.length; i++) {
    if (convradios[i].checked) {
    return true;
    }
} return false;
    
   
}
```

It seems to only acknowledge a requirement for "Convenience of delivery" before submitting instead of taking the first questions requirement now.

Sorry i'm new to this but what i want is for the form to check that a rating is selected on each question before proceeding. I don't want to use /required as i want to insert custom error message underneath the rating required which is why i haven't used that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, include the HTML for the radio buttons as well.

Comment: Where is `conv-rating`?

Answer (score 0):

Your are returning from the **`for`** loops too early, which is why the rest of the code where `conradios` **for** loop resides is unreachable.

Correct this by place the `return false;` statement just before the last curly brace of the **`for`** loop, not after it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < easeradios.length; i++) {
    if (easeradios[i].checked) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Do the same for the second loop as well:

```
for (var i = 0; i < convradios.length; i++) {
    if (convradios[i].checked) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```